# Unable to find peers when connecting through tor proxy

Tags: network, peers, tor

I have tor running as a service on my computer and start bitcoind with -proxy=127.0.0.1:9050 but it fails to find any seeds through DNS or anything during startup, and even after leaving it on for more than a day it still not finding peers. I'm not getting any errors with connection or anything, and if I change port to for example 9051, it complains indicating that tor is running ok.
Also, if I run it without the proxy option I get peers immediately and syncing starts right away. Can someone please help me? I'm running 0.17.1.

Here is also a little bit of the console print during startup. I was running it without proxy right before this so it got a few blocks:

```
2019-03-12T00:45:31Z Loaded 8954 addresses from peers.dat  23ms
2019-03-12T00:45:31Z init message: Loading banlist...
2019-03-12T00:45:31Z init message: Starting network threads...
2019-03-12T00:45:31Z addcon thread start
2019-03-12T00:45:31Z init message: Done loading
2019-03-12T00:45:31Z net thread start
2019-03-12T00:45:31Z opencon thread start
2019-03-12T00:45:31Z dnsseed thread start
2019-03-12T00:45:31Z msghand thread start
2019-03-12T00:45:42Z Loading addresses from DNS seeds (could take a while)
2019-03-12T00:45:42Z 0 addresses found from DNS seeds
2019-03-12T00:45:42Z dnsseed thread exit
2019-03-12T00:46:02Z Syncing txindex with block chain from height 13187
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you confirmed that tor is working correctly, say with a web browser? Temporarily set it to use a SOCKS5 proxy at 127.0.0.1:9050.

For more verbose information, try starting bitcoin with

commandline:
**-debug=1**
*or*
**-debug=tor**

bitcoin.conf:
**debug=1**
*or*
**debug=tor**